# Is there any good place to start learnig how to make a 2d game for android

Tags: language-agnostic

I have look eveywhere on the web. I've look at lunar lander with surfaceView ,snake, jetboy.I've even bought pro android games only to find that it dosen't work I also read up on open gl but they all leave out informait like how do you postion you image with diffent sceen.

if you know any good link can you post them because I'm more confuse then evey right now

thankyou.

Comment: This would be better at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to a project that I have (haven't worked on it for a few months). It is a 2D mini MMO game that I started a while back for my college senior project. All the code is open source if you want to take a look at it. I developed the graphics with OpenGL ES.

There is a lot more here than you need, but if you have any more questions, just let me know.

[Crystal Main Page](http://www.xp-dev.com/summary/81727)
[Crystal Android Code](http://www2.xp-dev.com/sc/browse/81727/%2Ftrunk%2FClient%2FAndroid?rev=101)